# Can we display login customer name on home page using theme template file and not using block? - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I tried to display login customer name using observer, block and controller. All working fine but when I try to display name using theme template file and it is not working. Can we do using theme template only? If yes then how?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

> app/design/frontend/Bhaveshpp/Covid/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Bhaveshpp\Theme\Block\Customer" name="home_page_customer" template="Magento_Cms::customer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Bhaveshpp/Covid/Magento_Cms/templates/customer.phtml

```
<?= $block->getCustomer()?>
```

> app/code/Bhaveshpp/Theme/Block/Customer.php

```
<?php
namespace Bhaveshpp\Theme\Block;
class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{

    protected $customer;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customer,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    ){
        $this->customer = $customer;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCustomer()
    {
        $customer = $this->customer;
        $customerName =  $customer->getName(); 
        return "Welcome ".$customerName;
    }
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: I already did it bro but I want the code of block in the template file because I stuck there. if you can help there then it will be a real help for me. thanks anyway, bro ....